# Vue-cli Webpack template not properly serving static fonts

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli

In my config/index.js, in the build section, I have

```
assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
assetsPublicPath: '/path/to/subdirectory/',
```

My static fonts that are coming from a theme template imported inside node_modules should then look up to **root/path/to/subdirectory/static/fonts/some-fonts.woff**. Is this correct?

However, in my production build, the build is looking for those files at:

**root/static/fonts/some-fonts.wff**

My Less file sample:

```
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 300;
        src: local('Source Sans Pro'),
        url(/static/fonts/source-sans-pro/source-sans-pro-v9-vietnamese_latin-ext_latin-300.eot) format('embedded-opentype'),
        url(/static/fonts/source-sans-pro/source-sans-pro-v9-vietnamese_latin-ext_latin-300.ttf) format('truetype'),
        url(/static/fonts/source-sans-pro/source-sans-pro-v9-vietnamese_latin-ext_latin-300.woff) format('woff'),
        url(/static/fonts/source-sans-pro/source-sans-pro-v9-vietnamese_latin-ext_latin-300.woff2) format('woff2');
    }
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font location is not the problem; if it works in your development environment then the font files are loading from node_modules as you eluded to.

The problem is with css-loader; [read their docs here](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader). The **public** path must be '/' only, and 'static' will then contain 'fonts' as a sub-directory in your build. I had a similar issue and this resolved it. If you attempt to do something other than '/' for the public path (for example, empty string) then you will break the vue-cli template way of doing things.

And that is the difference — you're not doing "webpack" where you have free reign to set whatever you want. With vue-cli you are accepting "their way" of configuring things (which I am not knocking). If you need more freedom to do custom configurations as you show above, consider webpack without vue-cli.

At any rate, make sure that you are touching BOTH the dev and build property maps within index.js; these PATH vars are repeated for each environment and sometimes coders don't remember to scroll down to the 'build' property and change those PATH values too.